# Malloc return 0?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, heap-memory, dev-c++

I'm doing a homework project in C using the Dev-C++ compiler. Strangely, I've stucked at a `malloc` function that returns me `0` which would mean that it is out of heap memory. I hardly doubt that the memory is full.
 I've included the `windows.h` library.

This is the problematic part of the function. The printf gives me:

> 00000000 ... 00000000 .... 005C1058

What is wrong here?

```
typedef struct tcat {
    char *namec;
    struct tcat *nextc;
    struct tprod *firstp; 
}CTGR;

typedef struct tprod {
    char *namep;
    float price;
    int qt;
    struct tprod *nextp;
}PRDCT;

void Srch(int i)
{
    //data base population
    int k,r;

    //categories of components
    CTGR *p,*primc;
    primc = (CTGR *)malloc(sizeof(CTGR));

    primc -> namec = "Resistances";
    p = primc -> nextc;
    p -> namec = "Capacitors";
    p -> nextc = 0;


    PRDCT *q,*primRP,*primCP;
    primRP = (PRDCT *)malloc(sizeof(PRDCT));
    primCP = (PRDCT *)malloc(sizeof(PRDCT));

    printf(" %p ... %p .... %p",primRP,primCP,primc);
    getch();
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @BillLynch , "What is wrong here?"

Comment: @BillLynch The formal question is `What is wrong here?` and the context is that `primRP` and `primCP` print out as `00000000`.

Comment: @GSerg: And in the question he answers it. `malloc()` is allowed to return `NULL` when it can't allocate your request.

Comment: @BillLynch The question is then, why, given the struct is so small and the memory is hardly close to being full. In fact I believe Bjorn Munch's answer is correct. The OP should veify that by moving the allocation lines to the top.

Comment: Ok, the question is, why it returns 0 while the heap memory is not full. I restarted the computer but the problem still contiunes. Heap = volatile. Why is this happening? I guess that the memory is ok, but the code is faulty somewhere.

Comment: As I explained, your assignments through p are writing into some unknown place in memory, to an address defined by whatever bytes were stored at primc -> nextc. If this happens to be some leftover pointer from malloc's internal bookkeeping, it's quite possible that you're messing up the heap and then all bets are off.

Comment: FYI: `malloc()` returns `NULL` for potentially 2 reasons: Out-of-memory (or more specifically, cannot allocate the requested size) 2) Size requested is 0.  In the 2nd situation, `malloc(0)` may instead return a non-NULL value.  The 2nd case does not likely apply here as `sizeof(PRDCT) != 0`.  Of course, if previous code has undefined behavior, anything is possible,

Comment: In the absence of a proper prototype for `malloc()` the compiler assumes it returns an `int` value (it doesn't so that in itself is already **UB**). The compiler then generates code to convert that `int` value to a pointer (the cast) and assign the converted value to the variable. This conversion does not necessarily result in the same value the real `malloc()` returned, resulting in an invalid value being put into `primc`. Do `#include <stdlib.h>` and remove the cast.

Answer (score 3):

```
p = primc -> nextc;
```

May be the culprit. That value is not set and could be anything, so when you assign through it, you're writing into some unpredictable place in memory.

Comment: I tried a printf of p. It gives me a valid adress. I guess that's not the problem. Also, this attribution is an ordinary one in structures as far as I know. It's just dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @GorganRazvan Any address is valid as far as the processor is concerned. You do not make an allocation here, you make the processor believe that `p` now points to a `tcat` when in fact it points to a random place in memory. Writing to that place may trip `malloc`.

Comment: So ... I guess this solves the problem then:     p = (CTGR *)malloc(sizeof(CTGR));
primc -> nextc = p;